# How to functions using firebase deploy and multiple packages.json?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

As I understand it, there are two packages.json files inside a firebase functions project. One resides in the functions directory and another in the top level directory for the project. My packages.json look as such:

functions/packages.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

packages.json

```
{
  "name": "a-server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "/functions/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "clean-deploy": "rm -rf functions/node_modules && cp -r node_modules/ functions/node_modules/ && cd functions && npm install",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "local-firebase": "firebase serve --only functions,hosting",
    "firebase-deploy": "firebase deploy",
    "start": "npm-run-all clean build lint --parallel watch:build local-firebase",
    "deploy": "npm-run-all clean-deploy build lint firebase-deploy",
    "commit": "git-cz"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.138.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "inversify": "^4.4.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/jwt-simple": "^0.5.33",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.46",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.38",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "commitizen": "^2.9.6",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

At first I thought what I could do is setup a script like the one shown for `deploy` in the packages.json under the top level directory; the intent being that I would copy all the node_modules to the functions directory, cd into it and then install its packages. However,firebase deploy doesn't recognize the dependencies in the root packages.json and returns:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'http-status-codes'
```

How can I get the functions package.json to recognize that there are dependencies in the top level packages.json? Or should I move all those dependencies inside `functions/packages.json`?

Comment: When you create a new project with `firebase init`, there is no package.json at the root of the project, just in functions.  Where did your top level package.json come from?  Functions will only recognize things under the functions folder and no where else.

Comment: Perfect. Did exactly that and it worked out great @DougStevenson. Thank you.